# Continue listening to Firestore updates on Android after closing app

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, android-workmanager

Currently I have written custom LiveData class, which adds snapshot listener to document reference while being observed, thus providing easy way to update UI. I want to continue listening to the same document after app closes, and show updates in notification.

What would be a good way to do that? I have little experience with services, etc. but if I understand corectly, I should use either WorkManager or foreground service. Is there a solution which would allow to use the same listener for UI and background?

Most answers to similar problems suggest using FCM + Cloud Functions to send updates, but for my purposes I would like to have ongoing notification and also I've experienced delays with cloud functions, so I'd like to avoid going this way.

Answer (score 0):

The way you'd like it to work is simply not possible anymore these days.

When your app is backgrounded on Android, the operating system will reduce its resources usage over time. This means that you can't rely on Firestore's usual mechanism to receive updates from the server, not even in a background service.

The idiomatic way to deliver updates to an app that is not active in the foreground is (as you've found) to send FCM messages to that app from a server or Cloud Functions. If you're having trouble making this work, we'll be better able to help if you post the [minimal, complete/standalone code with which we can reproduce where you got stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I thought that Foreground Service was supposed to behave almost exactly as a normal, open application without view. Also in documentation it looks like this service is exactly to avoid background limitations. https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#services Or are there limitations specific to firestore?

Comment: There is nothing specific to Firestore as far as I know. If you think it will work, I'd recommend giving it a try and reporting back. I just haven't heard from anyone successfully doing this, but if it works, it sure would be simpler/more direct than the tried-and-proven FCM tickle-to-trigger-a-refresh approach.